# Winter Bash hat challenge 2016 - as a community, do we have all the hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Since [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) has started - let's see who can get the hats.  Record any hats you have below.

For our leaderboard: [Travel Winter Bash 2016 Leaderboard](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I feel like this has to be un-[meta-tag:featured] at the very least...

Comment: Isn't it time to get this un-featured?

Answer (score 11):

### **Hat - and owners**

**6** - [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**011** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)

**24** - [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Robert Columbia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47855/robert-columbia), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**180** -

**925** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [pnuts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4995/pnuts), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)

**8,243,721** - [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Abominable** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Amped Up** - [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Blue in the Face** - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Bûche de Noël** - [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Robert Columbia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47855/robert-columbia), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)

**Cutting the Cord** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Don't Want to Taco 'Bout it** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Elementary** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Egoist** - [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Epiphany** - [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke), [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans)

**Fiery** -  [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**First Responder** - [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)

**Hero of Questions** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**I Am Your Father** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Robert Columbia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47855/robert-columbia), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**I Have A Little Dreidel** - [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)

**Just Here for the Hat** - [Everybody (by design)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users)

**Like Clockwork** - [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Loungin’ Around** - [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Mmmm Bacon** - [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Skifans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30717/skifans), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)

**Mild Mannered** - ([Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) not on Travel)

**No Longer Grinchy** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Philantropist** - [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Polymath** - [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Running Ragged** - [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Search You Must** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Snaphat** - [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**The Hatter** - [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**This Is Fine** - [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Trendsetter** - [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Where in the World** - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [Robert Columbia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47855/robert-columbia), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

Comment: I would not mind if someone adds my hats, but I can not (yet) be bothered to do it myself. Only 22 here and one more on an other site.

Comment: @Willeke I added your hats for you. That was an excuse to fill in hats missing from the list ;) In case you win Philantropist tomorrow, you will still need to add that, though.

Comment: I will if I find time later on, you will have to add the hats of at least one more person, as I do see the 180 on the list but I do not own it.

Comment: Added mine in. I managed 31 network-wide, but only 15 here.

Answer (score 1):

No. Impossible because not all hats were available to all Communities, eg:

[This year, was the first year we introduced some site-specific hats. Stack Overflow has two products, Developer Story and Documentation, which are not available on the rest of the network, so we awarded hats for participating in them.](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/)